# Error inserting data using owner.table in Oracle, works without owner

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have created a table in `Oracle` with the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE MYOWNER.MY_TABLE (
       TBL_ID          NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
       ...
)TABLESPACE MYOWNER_TABLESPACE;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM TBL FOR MYOWNER.MY_TABLE;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON MYOWNER.MY_TABLE TO MYOWNER;
```

The following insert statement works, using `MYOWNER`:

```
Insert into TBL
   (TBL_ID, ...)
 Values
   (8, ...);
```

But if I add the owner to the insert statements (for script conventions in the company I'm working, I have to add them) is throwing the error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. Insert statement that's not working:

```
Insert into MYOWNER.TBL
   (TBL_ID, ...)
 Values
   (8, ...);
```

The question is: What can I do to allow the insert statement `Insert into MYOWNER.TBL` to work properly? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe that one of the answers provided is useful for you and I think you can select the better for you and mark it as correct that is accept it. Maybe even vote them up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have your table:

```
SQL> conn alek/alek@test
Connected.
SQL> create table alek.alek_table(n number);

Table created.
```

And you create a `PUBLIC SYNONYM` for it, so that it can be accessed with a different name, with no need to write the schema, by whatever login user (with the needed permissions):

```
SQL> create public synonym a_tab for alek_table;

Synonym created.
```

You can use the synonym to access the table

```
SQL> select * from a_tab;

no rows selected
```

You can even use the simple table name, if you login with the owner user:

```
SQL> select * from alek_table;

no rows selected
```

You can always use the schema.table way:

```
SQL> select * from alek.alek_table;

no rows selected
```

But you can not use schema.synonym way:

```
SQL> select * from alek.a_tab;
select * from alek.a_tab
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

because you created a `public` synonym, and this is not considered a schema object, but a `public` one.

Differently, if you create a private synonym, you have a schema object and you can use schema.synonym to access the table:

```
SQL> create synonym a_tab_private for alek_table;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from alek.a_tab_private;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Works like a charm and great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
CREATE SYNONYM MYOWNER.TBL FOR MYOWNER.MY_TABLE
```

> PUBLIC
>
> Specify PUBLIC to create a public synonym. Public synonyms are
>   accessible to all users. However each user must have appropriate
>   privileges on the underlying object in order to use the synonym.
>
> When resolving references to an object, Oracle Database uses a public
>   synonym only if the object is not prefaced by a schema and is not
>   followed by a database link.
>
> If you omit this clause, then the synonym is private and is accessible
>   only within its schema. A private synonym name must be unique in its
>   schema.
>
> Notes on Public Synonyms  The following notes apply to public
>   synonyms:
>
> If you create a public synonym and it subsequently has dependent
>   tables or dependent valid user-defined object types, then you cannot
>   create another database object of the same name as the synonym in the
>   same schema as the dependent objects.
>
> Take care not to create a public synonym with the same name as an
>   existing schema. If you do so, then all PL/SQL units that use that
>   name will be invalidated.
>
> schema
>
> Specify the schema to contain the synonym. If you omit schema, then
>   Oracle Database creates the synonym in your own schema. You cannot
>   specify a schema for the synonym if you have specified PUBLIC.

From: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm

Comment: It also works perfectly, but explanation is not as clear as the accepted answer

Comment: @RafaelPalomino thanks for the vote up. It is the official explanation :)